# What is entity graph in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have been looking into some Entity framework tutorials and I have come across the word **Entity Graph**. I haven't got a clear idea about this term and its use. Can anyone provide info on this topic like what it is and its use in the context of entity framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When instantiated objects are joined together in a relationship they are referred to as
a graph, or an entity graph. The Entity Framework has some important rules about how
graphs are maintained.

Example, if you have a User(Entity) graph that consists of a User with Roles, Features.

- When you detach the User
- The User will be disconnected from this graph and the releationship references (Graph edges) will be destroyed.
- You cannot travel from User to Roles/Features,  because the graph edges (releationships) are destroyed.

I recommend you buy the "Programming Entity Framework DbContext" book (author: EF-Queen Julia Lerman) and you will find there a good explanation:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do

Answer (score 0):

In Jpa hibernate fetching entities with associtions has always been a question for performance. Lazily loading associations with in a transaction again and again results in n+1 select issues and to avoid such issues JPQL join fetch and Criteria api joins are used. But fetching data with these two also result in Cross join issues means Cross join of all table records are returned to apllication by hibernate. Also altering fetch variable defined in annotaions on entity level is also not a good option for some cases. Hence to solve the above two issues entity graphs has been intoduced. All nodes defined in entity graphs are always eager fetched irrespective of their definition on entity level. These graphs are passed as a hint to queries . By passing graphs as a hint Cross join issues are solved as well as run time alteration of fetch behaviour can take place. For code you can check my github repository :

https://github.com/vaneetkataria/Jpa-Hibernate/blob/master/jdbcToJpaMigration/src/test/java/com/katariasoft/technologies/jpaHibernate/entity/fetch/entitygraph/dynamic/MultiInstructorsDynamicEntityGrpahTests.java