# Entity Framework is creating new child object when parent object is created

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have 2 classes, which work as a one to many relationship. The structure of this relationship is as follows:

```
public partial class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }


public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

When I created a new Employee object, and assign an existing Department to it, EF creates a new Employee object as well as a new Department record in my db, but this is not what I want. I want the employee record to be created but to reference the existing department object. Here is my business code:

```
IEmployeeBiz employeeBiz = new EmployeeBiz();
IDepartmentBiz departmentBiz = new DepartmentBiz();

Department department = new Department();
department.Name = "Testing";
departmentBiz.Add(department); // add to db

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.FirstName = "James";
employee.LastName = "Bond";
employee.Department = department; // add existing department to new employee
employeeBiz.Add(employee); // add to db
```

As you can see, I am assigning the Department object to employee.Department, the DAL code for this creation is the following, I am using a generic DAL for this:

```
public virtual void Add(T[] items)
{
    using (var context = new DbConnect())
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I know that I can get over this by just assigning the departmentId on my employee object, but I want my code to work where I just assign the child Department object to my parent Employee object.

How can I get this to work in the way I want?

Comment: `but this is not what I want.` Why is this not what you want?

Comment: @mjwills because I want to just reference the entire object, I don't want to have to reference the id to foreign key to. I was hoping that EF would do this, it's one of the main reasons why I'm using it

Answer (score 0):

<strike>"Department" has a collection of "Employee" AND "Employee" has the Property of "Department". That is a recursive design, don't know, if EF can handle this. It looks like a design error.</strike>

Btw: using GraphDiff is elegant in EF. It is a not well documented, but very vell working EF-extension for updating whole graphs. https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/

Comment: What do you mean by "graph"?

And what is wrong with my table design?

Comment: Oh man! Sorry, your table design is ok, my fault - I mixed things up. graph: Instantiated objects joined together in a relationship are referred to as a graph, or an entity graph. (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788860/what-is-entity-graph-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I can see what you mean about not very well documented. I can't find anything to get started!

Comment: This is the original page of the developer of graphdiff. [http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/) There is a brief introduction and many useful comments. But normally the introduction should be enough to cover 99,9% of all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your one-to-many relationship is not configured correctly. Your employee needs to specify a foreign key to the Department it belongs to

```
class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId {get; set;}

     // every employee belongs to exactly one Department
     public int DepartmentId {get; set;}
     public virtual Department Department {get; set;}

     ... // other properties, not meaningful for this question
}
```

See [configure one-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

If you want to introduce an employee as well as a new Department you can do this as follows:

```
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employe()
{
     FirstName = ...;
     ...

     Department = new Department()
     {
         Name = "My beautiful launderette",
     },
});
```

If you want to introduce a new Employee into an existing department you'll either have to fetch this Department first, or just assign the DepartmentId

```
int departmentId = ...
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employe()
{
     FirstName = ...;
     ...

     DepartmentId = departmentId,
});
```

If you fetched your existing department differently, then you ought to have an Id that you can use:

```
Department existingDepartment = ..
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employe()
{
     FirstName = ...;
     ...

     DepartmentId = existingDepartmenr.DepartmentId,
});
```

Alternatively, but not advisable, because you won't see easily whether you are using an existing department or creating a new department:

```
Department someDepartment = ..
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employe()
{
     FirstName = ...;
     ...

     Department = someDepartment,
});
```

Entity framework will detect whether someDepartment already exists or not using someDepartment.DepartmentId. So why not use it yourself? It will only protect you and future readers from your code from creating a new Department by accident.

Finally: the creation of the Hashset in the constructor of Department is useless. It will be immediately discarded when you use it:

```
// fetch some departments:
var result = myDbContext.Departments
    .Where(department => department.Name = ...)
    .ToList();
```

Here ever department will be created, with an empty hashset, that will immediately be replaced by the virtual ICollection fetched from the database

```
// Introduce a Department with several employees:
var introducedDepartment = myDbContext.Departments.Add(new Department()
{
    Name = ...
    Employees = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() {Name = ... etc},
        new Employee() {Name = ... etc},
        new Employee() {Name = ... etc},
    },
});
```

Here a department with a HashSet is created. This hashset is immediately discarded and replaced by a new list of employees.

So why construct the HashSet anyway?

Comment: I want to add this functionality that you wrote:

Department someDepartment = ..
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employe()
{
     FirstName = ...;
     ...

     Department = someDepartment,
});

But EF creates a new Department when I do this.

Comment: As I wrote: this is because you didn't define the foreign key to the department in your Employee

Comment: I've added the extra field you mentioned but I still get the Department created anew?